# A Spring DAO that can adapt to changes in the data

Tags: spring, mongodb, architecture, dao

For application developers, I suppose the traditional paradigm for writing an application with domain objects that can be persisted to an underlying data store (SQL database for arguments sake), is to write the domain objects and then write (or generate) the table structure. There is a tight coupling between what the domain object looks like and what the structure of underlying data store looks like. So if you want to add a piece of information to your domain object, you add the field to your code and then add a column to the appropriate database table. All familiar?

This is all well and good for data stores that have a well defined structure (I'm mainly talking about SQL databases whereby the tables and columns are pre-defined and fixed), but  now a number of alternatives to the ubiquitous SQL database exist and these often do not constrain the data in this way. For instance, MongoDB is a *NoSQL* database whereby you divide data into *collections* but aside from that there is no structuring of the data. You don't define new columns when you want to add a new field.

Now to the question: given the flexibility of a data store like MongoDB, how would one go about achieving a similar kind of flexibility in the domain objects that represent this data? So for instance if I'm using Spring and creating my own domain obejcts, when I add a "middleName" field to my data, how can I avoid having to add a "middleName" field to my domain object? I'm looking for some kind of mechanism/approach/framework to dynamically inspect the data and have access to it in my domain object without having to make a code change every time. All ideas welcome.

Comment: so you want a change in your data store schema to dynamically modify your domain object?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a couple of choices:

1. You can use a dynamic programming language and not have domain objects (clojure for example)
2. If you're fixed on using java, the mongo java driver returns data in DBObject which is essentially a Map. So the default behavior already provides what you want. It's only when you map the DBObject into domain objects, using a library like morphia (or spring-data), that you even have to worry about domain objects at all.

But, if I was using java, I would stick with the standard convention of domain objects mapped via morphia, because I think adding a field is a very minor inconvenience when compared against the benefits.

Comment: Right, and I would also add that, having added a new field dynamically, you still have to have some method to get to the field.  In Java, that is typically a getter/setter.  Otherwise you have some strange code going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is inherintly paradoxical-
On one hand, you want to have domain objects, i.e. objects that represent the data (and behaviour) of your problem domain.
On the other hand, you say that you don't want your domain objects to be explicitly influenced by changes to the data.
But when you have objects that represent your problem domain, you want to do just that- to represent your problem domain.
So that if, for example, middle name is added, then your representation of the real-life 'User' entity *should* change to accomodate this change to the real-life user; perhaps not only by adding this piece of data to your object, but also adding some related behaviour (validation of middle name, or some functionality related to it).

In essense, what I'm trying to say here is that when you have (classic OO) domain objects, you may need to change your behaviour / functionality along with your data, and since you don't have any automatic way of changing your behaviour, the question of automatically changing your data becomes irrelevant.

If you don't want behaviour associated with your data, then you essentialy have DTOs, and @Kevin's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it sounds more like you're looking for some kind of blackbox DTO where, like you describe, fields are added or removed "arbitrarily" depending on the data. This makes me inclined to suggest a simple `Map` to do the job. You can't really have a domain-driven design if your domain model is constantly changing.

Comment: I suppose what I'm looking for is "model-driven" design